# Irreducibility criteria over polynomial rings

Tags: polynomials

This is very basic question, but  often puts me in confusion. Let $Z$ be the ring of integers and $Z[X]$ be the polynomial ring over $Z$. Then
What is $Z[X]/\langle 6x\rangle$?
Is it $Z_6\times Z$ or $Z_6[X]\times Z$

Comment: Can you find a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ (to any other ring) whose kernel would be $\langle 6x\rangle$?

Comment: I changed $Z[X]/<6x>$ to $Z[X]/\langle 6x\rangle$.  That is standard usage.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan thank you very much.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks for editing